# Add a comment to a vdproj file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

If there anyway to add a header comment to a vdproj file?

```
<!-- HEADER COMMENT -->

"DeployProject"
{
"VSVersion" = "3:800"
"ProjectType" = "8:{978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}"
"IsWebType" = "8:FALSE"
"ProjectName" = "8:LuceneMonitorSetup"
"LanguageId" = "3:1033"
"CodePage" = "3:1252"
...
}
```